# Language Translation of Markdown file using Docusaurus

Tags: markdown, i18next, docusaurus, language-translation, mdxjs

Is it possible to implement a `SIDEBAR_LABEL` language translation of Markdown/mdx file using Docusaurus?

https://docusaurus.io/docs/i18n/git#translate-the-files

```
mkdir -p i18n/fr/docusaurus-plugin-content-docs/current
cp -r docs/i18n/fr/docusaurus-plugin-content-docs/current

mkdir -p i18n/fr/docusaurus-plugin-content-blog
cp -r blog/i18n/fr/docusaurus-plugin-content-blog

mkdir -p i18n/fr/docusaurus-plugin-content-pages
cp -r src/pages/**.md i18n/fr/docusaurus-plugin-content-pages
cp -r src/pages/**.mdx i18n/fr/docusaurus-plugin-content-pages
```

I've tried to follow their steps but it's not working for me. Please help me implement a Language translation for Sidebar. Thank you!